# redirect to another page after successful insertion of data via AJAX

Tags: jsp, jquery

After successful insertion of date I want to redirect to another JSP page.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "register.jsp",
                data: datastring,
                success:function(){            
                                window.location.href = "nextPage.jsp";
                }
```

but I can not redirect to another page (nextPage.jsp) but the insertion of data to database is successful. How to redirect to
another page???

I also tried

```
success:function(){
$("divid").load("nextPage.jsp") }
```

but this is also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of doing this

```
window.location.href = "nextPage.jsp";
```

do this
use

```
var url = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/your_jsp';
window.location.replace(url);
```